# How to import github pluggin to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

so I found this VR gesture pluggin on gitHub https://github.com/edwonia/VR-Infinite-Gesture and I`m trying to import it to Unity. So I have downloaded the zip file from he before mentioned link in gitHub, what is the process of importing this pluggin in unity ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unzip, copy the whole folder into the `assets` folder of your project.

Comment: Wow wow there cowboy , "you`ve gotta excuse my friend here, he is a little slow" , So after I unzip the zip file I`ve downloaded, I create a folder in my assets, I try and paste the folder I just copied that I`ve unziped , but I dont get that option in the drop down menu...I get an option like , import asset, import package ?

Comment: try windows explorer, partner!